# GUI Multi Thread TCP Server-Client - GUI crash when starting listener

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, tcplistener, tcpserver

I am making a simple TCP server with GUI.

The problem I have is that when I start listening for client connections the GUI / Application stops working.

Most likely this is due to the while true that I have added. I'm not very familiar with C#, sorry if the error is obvious...

My code

```cs
private void StartListener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int serverPort = int.Parse(ServerPort.Text);
    string serverIP = ServerIP.Text;
    try {
        Socket ServerListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), serverPort);
        ServerListener.Bind(endpoint);
        ServerListener.Listen(9999999);
        MessageBox.Show("The server is listening for connections", "Server is listening");
        Socket ClientSocket = default(Socket);
        int counter = 0;
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        while (true) {
            counter++;
            ClientSocket = ServerListener.Accept();
            Thread UserThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => frm.User(ClientSocket)));
            UserThread.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Server is not listening\n\n- IP Server or Port may be incorrect\n- Error: {0}", error.Message), "Server listener error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

public void User(Socket client)
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
        int size = client.Receive(msg);
        client.Send(msg, 0, size, SocketFlags.None);
    }
}
```

Any help is more than welcome! Thank you very much for the community support!

Thanks and Best regards,

I have tried to search for support in the forum and on the Internet but unfortunately there is no help for TCP Server/Client with GUI.

Comment: It's good that you posted your code formatted correctly but it is important to post only the relevant code. All those namespace imports and empty event handlers only serve to distract from the issue. As with screenshots, only show us what we need to see to understand the issue. Anything else just makes that understanding more difficult and reduces the likelihood of you getting the help you want.

Comment: Based on what you have said, your app is not crashing at all. The GUI freezing is not a crash. It's still an issue that needs fixing, of course. As you say, the issue is your infinite loop. If the UI thread is executing that loop, it can't do anything else. Don't do stuff like that on the UI thread. Either do it synchronously on a secondary thread or do it asynchronously. The `Socket` class you're using supports multiple asynchronous patterns, so look into those. `BeginRecieve` and `EndReceive` are what you would have used previously but now `ReceiveAsync` is also an option. Research time.

Comment: Code is not freezing, it is simply waiting for client to send a message.  client.Receive(msg); is blocking and is waiting.  If you want do run other code while waiting for the client to send a message you need to use Async methods instead of Sync methods.